# Dropbox is asking me to change location to Ext4

Tags: ext4, dropbox

My Dropbox keeps telling me, that it needs to be moved to `ext4` filesystem.

[image]

The problem is, that when I have a look at my disk, I see this:

[image]

It seems, that my filesystem already is `ext4`.

Do you have any idea, what could be wrong? I found a similar question [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Syncing-and-uploads/Dropbox-client-warns-me-that-it-ll-stop-syncing-in-Nov-why/m-p/290372).

I'm using only encrypted home folder - could the problem be solved just by moving my Dropbox folder outside of it?

Comment: See also summary of possible reasons here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1087376/29252

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dropbox doesn't support eCryptfs.

As per [this official documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-requirements#desktop)

> Note: ecryptfs is not supported, but Dropbox will continue to sync with supported file systems that are encrypted via full disk encryption (e.g. LUKS)

Also another important note

> If you’re running a supported operating system, but you see a message that your computer is unsupported, you may be [running Dropbox in an unsupported configuration](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-requirements).

Answer (score 1):

You can make unencrypted file system on encrypted `home` and put Dropbox folder inside.

1. Unlink your host and quit Dropbox.
2. Make storage file (count depend of your Dropbox size)

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=~/dropboxStorage bs=1024 count=3000000
```

3. Make file system inside

```
$ mkfs.ext4 ~/dropboxStorage
```

4. Localize Dropbox folder and rename it (you can remove it but I prefer to rename if smtf went wrong):

```
$ mv ~/Dropbox ~/Dropbox.mvd
```

5. Edit fstab, change ownership of Dropbox mountpoint and mount it (now you don’t need sudo)

```sh
$ mkdir ~/Dropbox
$ sudo vim /etc/fstab    # add at the end of fstab
/home/username/dropboxStorage /home/username/Dropbox ext4 noauto,user 0 0
$ sudo chown username ~/Dropbox
$ mount ~/Dropbox
# check it
$ mount | grep Dropbox
/home/username/dropboxStorage on /home/username/Dropbox type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user=username
```

6. Start Dropbox and relink again -- it works!

I have a lot of hosts linked and quicker and safer for me is download Dropbox again. You cat try to do `cp -a`, `rsync` or `tar -`. But beware.

You have to set starting Dropbox after mount Dropbox storage. Or turn off start Dropbox in `gnome-session-properties` and start it manually after login. First `mount` then `dropbox`

Answer (score 1):

### Dropbox has brought back support for ZFS, XFS, Btrfs and eCryptFS

Dropbox has brought back support for ZFS, XFS, Btrfs and eCryptFS on Linux. A Dropbox [client update](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Desktop-client-builds/Beta-Build-77-3-127/td-p/354660) brings back support for ZFS and XFS on 64-bit Linux systems, and eCryptFS and Btrfs on all Linux systems.

Links:

- [Dropbox Brings Back Support For ZFS, XFS, Btrfs And eCryptFS On Linux](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/dropbox-brings-back-support-for-zfs-xfs.html)
- [Maestral](https://github.com/SamSchott/maestral-dropbox) lightweight open source Dropbox client for Linux

Answer (score -1):

I have Ext4 partition on Linux Mint system and the same notification to change dropbox folder , but i resoved with UnlockMe sotware and his dropbox fix option . You can see it in attached image .  This was a solution for me . Bye

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehiid.png]

Comment: This looks great, the only thing is, I don't see any Dropbox Startup Fix option in Lubuntu. Is there any way to make it appear?