# Will Dropbox no longer work under Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: dropbox

I use currently Ubuntu 16.04. When Dropbox loads, I get a message saying that it will stop synchronizing in November.

However, in this page

https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux

it is stated that Ubuntu 14.04 or higher is compatible.

Why then the warning message?

Shall I upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Do you have an encrypted Home?

Comment: I believe that pomsky might be correct.  See https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-requirements#desktop but it appears that full encryption of the hard drive like LUKS will be supported.

Comment: @pomsky I don't know. How can I determine it? Is the encryption done during the installation of the system?

Comment: @AlfieGonzález To check see https://askubuntu.com/questions/146511/how-to-check-if-your-home-folder-and-swap-partition-are-encrypted-using-terminal

Comment: @pomsky According to the post referred by @Terrance, my home directory is encrypted, since it contains a `.ecryptfs` directory. And the post also says that `ecryptfs` is not supported. But then why until now have I been able to synchronize Dropbox if such encryption is not supported? What should I do?

Comment: Here you go:https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Syncing-and-uploads/Dropbox-client-warns-me-that-it-ll-stop-syncing-in-Nov-why/td-p/290058

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropbox - change location to Ext4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066571/dropbox-change-location-to-ext4)

Comment: Is there a way to revert the encryption, or will I have to create again a home directory from scratch and avoid encrypting it with ecryptfs?

Comment: @AlfieGonzález Dropbox *used to* support eCryptFS, but they'll stop from November. See this to remove encryption from your Home: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption