# Is it possible to create separated unencrypted ext4 filesystem?

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, encryption, disk-usage, dropbox

So, I'm thinking about my possibilities considering [Dropbox is not supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066571/dropbox-is-asking-me-to-change-location-to-ext4) on the encrypted `ext4` filesystems anymore.

My first thought was, that I could create a new, unencrypted disk partition just for the Dropbox - is it possible to do it safely?

And if it is, then how?

---

My OS is Lubuntu 18.04 and my current disk looks like this, with my home folder being encrypted:

[image]

Comment: Faced with the same issue, I decided to move to [pCloud](https://www.pcloud.com/). Not a perfect solution but seems to work (so far).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an ext4 filesystem already, you can just:

```
dropbox stop
sudo mkdir /my_dropbox_home
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /my_dropbox_home
mv ~/Dropbox /my_dropbox_home/
```

Then run dropbox with that fake home folder:

```
HOME=/my_dropbox_home dropbox start
```

I got that trick from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1265649/52910).

If you didn't have an ext4 filesystem, then you could create a file with an ext4 partition inside it, and then mount that partition.  I wrote [a script](https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/17bee2e5028ea53bc73f255992bab218) to do that.  Use at your own risk though!

Answer (score 0):

You can resize/shrink your Partition2 and create a new partition using a linux live drive, but it is very unreasonable to do this.

Why not just adding a new folder under somewhere else outside your home in original rootfs and make sure the owner and group is correct?

Comment: Thank you Alvin! I'm just not sure, that Dropbox can be placed outside the home folder...

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: One thing, I don't know why but Dropbox has some strange limitation. I create /test under /, with normal user/group, but Dropbox refuses to use it.  I'll need to use something like /test/test.  I think this is a bug since I cannot move it back to my un-encrypted home after I move it out.

Comment: Exactly! Do you have any workaround in mind?