# Create new location for Dropbox

Tags: filesystem, encryption, dropbox, ecryptfs

Running Ubuntu on a Dell XPS, dual-booting with Windows that I hardly use. I encrypted my home folder when installing 16.04, and now Dropbox won't sync anymore as they no longer support .ecryptfs.

What's the simplest solution so that I can keep using Dropbox? (I would consider switching but I share folders with other people who use it so it's more convenient to stick with it.)

I came across this solution: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9b1qyk/dropbox_syncing_stopping_in_november/e50a17j/
, but I'm worried that I might erase the dropbox folder I already have.

I'm still a bit of a newbie and get a bit nervous when messing around with filesystems, so I'd appreciate any detailed tips. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090824/dropbox-has-just-force-halted-syncing-probably-because-i-am-using-standard-16-0/1090836#1090836) and duplicates associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I would like to move Dropbox to an unencrypted folder, but unfortunately "/home" is also encrypted. Can I move to another unencrypted location?

Comment: Yes, you can move Dropbox to another location. `/var/` may be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks - I had an issue with this at first, but fixed it, thanks to the answer by @florian-echtler on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066045/dropbox-ext4-isnt-ext4 which says that "The target folder (or Dropbox sync folder) needs to be at least two levels beneath the mountpoint, as described in this post. This is obviously a facepalm-worthy bug"

Answer (score 0):

> What's the simplest solution so that I can keep using Dropbox?

The *simplest* solution is not at all simple, but if you wish to try anyway see this answer for how to stop protecting your home directory using encryption:

"[How to stop using built-in home directory encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption)"

Alternatively, stop using Ubuntu and switch to an operating system that is better supported by Dropbox, such as Windows or macOS. You'll have to decide which is a higher priority for you, basic security for your data on Ubuntu or the ability to keep using Dropbox (running on something else).

Comment: Stop using home encryption, or stop using linux are the "simplest"? Ugh...  moving the dropbox folder has a GUI "click here to move" IIRC