# How to install dropbox on a usb persistent live? 18.04

Tags: live-usb, dropbox

I made a USB persistent live and I tried to install dropbox.

I am having the message that I should move Dropbox to a supported file system.

How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dropbox: ext4 isn't ext4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066045/dropbox-ext4-isnt-ext4)

Comment: A Full install of Ubuntu to USB should do anything an internal install can do, including run Dropbox. For an external install that works on both UEFI and BIOS see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb/1107338#1107338